# Search suggestions with caching if searched was made previously (Java)

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have a search bar, and as soon as user types in he must be shown suggestions by querying the database. But if he tries to enter those same characters in sequence I want a way to cache the previous suggestions and return back to him without querying DB. I can use a hashmap but I need a much better implementation. I'm using hibernate as an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can plug a cache into your ORM (I'd suggest [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/), here's [the corresponding manual section](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/hibernate/))

Or you can use a programmatic cache on the application layer. Here, I'd suggest a [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

If you use Spring, then both of these are also available through [Spring's own Cache abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)